# Delay this Javascript FOR Loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, parse-platform

This `LOOP` queries the Parse.com server & then plays with the results if any. The problem is that when `nArray` is greater than 100, the function exceeds the query/burst limit of Parse.com CloudCode & it fails.

One idea would be to delay the `LOOP` for a second after every 100 `LOOPS`, but I'm not sure how to do that. Any other solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance,

```
 for (var k = 1; k < nArray.length; k++) {

     (function (k, mArray) { // <-- define an inline function

         query2.equalTo("username", nArray[k]); // BURST LIMIT EXCEEDS

         query2.find({

             success: function (results) {


                 if (results.length !== 0) {
                     var object = results[0];
                     var compareUserEmail = object.get('email');
                     if (compareUserEmail !== userEmail) {
                         // alert("The result is equal to" + object.get('Name'));


                         mArray.push({
                             name: object.get('Name'),
                             email: object.get('email'),
                             bloxID: object.get('bloxID')
                         });



                         gameScore.set("filtered", mArray);

                         gameScore.save(null, {
                             success: function (gameScore) {

                                 response.success("Success!");
                                 alert('New object created with objectId: ' + gameScore.id);
                             },
                             error: function (gameScore, error) {

                                 alert('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.description);
                             }
                         });

                     }
                 };
             },
             error: function () {}
         });
     })(k, mArray);
     // <-- call it after definition using (k)


 };
```

Comment: Have you attempting any solutions at all?

Comment: Yes, I have tried setInterval, unfortunately It's not supported by Pasre.com Cloud Code

Answer (score 1):

You've got a couple of issues to deal with.

The reason Parse.com doesn't support setInterval is because that would be inviting disaster. It terminates your Cloud Code if it takes too long, so letting you add delays would just increase the chance your code is terminated before completion.

The reason Parse.com has a burst limit is that this usually suggest "you are doing it wrong (tm)". In your case you are looping through an array and running a query for each item in the array. Instead you should be using the [containedIn](http://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Query.html#containedIn) method to get all records for the array in one go. If you are getting more than 100 items in your array you can choose to increase the record limit to 1000, but first consider carefully if this is really what you need.

Given that you are modifying a lot of objects and saving them all, consider using the [saveAll](http://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Object.html#.saveAll) method to save them all in one hit too.

You might want to consider batching these operations, but be aware of the [restrictions](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-resource) on overall duration for Cloud Code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `setInterval`:

```
var i = 0;
var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    if(i < nArray.length) {
        ... your code ...

        i++;
    } else {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
}, 100); //every 100ms; change it to what you need
```

Comment: I tried setInterval initially but it's not supported by Parse.com CloudCode, any other ways?